# Magento 2 CLI commands not working in windows 10

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cli

> I installed magento 2 setup on windows 7 and windows 10. In windows 7
>   commands works fine but in windows 10, nothing happens after running
>   any of magento 2 CLI commands and not even it gives any error.

[image]

Tried commands in shell script. Result is in non readable format.

[image]

Comment: Please share some more details because i am using Window 10 and its working fine in my system.

Comment: I have attached screenshot of commands on cmd. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Open Shell Command from xampp control panel

Comment: try cygwin and open as admin rights

Comment: Tried commands in shell commands , got result in non readable format.

Comment: Hi @ArunPal i am facing the same issue how did u fix this issue? could u please tell me the procedure

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kcwqq3 windows 10 and PHP Version 7.0.13 unable to execute magento 2 commands

Comment: Hi bro can you please help me to provide answer for the above issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) **Click XAMPP icon to launch its cPanel**

(2) **Click on Shell button**

[image]

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kcwqq3 windows 10 and PHP Version 7.0.13 unable to execute magento 2 commands

Comment: Hi Divyesh can you please provide reply to my above comment

Comment: check this images , it may help you:- https://magenticians.com/install-magento-2-on-localhost-using-xampp/

Answer (score 2):

Please Use Git Bash For Command Line In Windows 10

https://git-scm.com/downloads

1- Start Wamp or Xamp Server

2- Go to Project Directory

3- Right Click and Select Git Bash Here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhPmv.png

4-Run magento commands here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu2kY.png

If you face any issue . please commit, i am available for help

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still looking for answer try

```
php bin\magento
```